query with jsonb filed of array of json elements
I have a column jsonb that contains an element:
"element": [
{"field": "2024-08-01", ...},
{"field": "2024-08-02", ...}
]

I need to create a query using sqlalchemy where I need to select rows with matching dates. My current function is:
def make_nested_date(query, value: dict):
    """
    Create nested date filter
    """
    date_from = isoparse(value.get('from'))
    date_to = isoparse(value.get('to'))
    query = query.where(
        and_(func.jsonb_array_elements(Table.c.data['element'])['field'].astext.cast(Date) >= date_from,
             func.jsonb_array_elements(Table.c.data['element'])['field'].astext.cast(Date) <= date_to)
    )
    return query

It doesn't work.
Postgresql 9.6
I tried to convert the json array to a date array, but I couldn't process it further.

Don't store JSON in the database. Use normal tables.

@Olivier, there are legitimate uses for JSON in the database. That's why JSON types were added. It's not clear whether this example is a good fit for JSON, but an order not to use them at all isn't terribly helpful.

@Chris "there are legitimate uses for JSON in the database" I agree, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

@Olivier I agree with you that maybe it is not quite appropriate to use json here. but it is not my decision to use it here.

In that case, can you show the generated SQL query? Remark: there is no need to convert to dates. You can compare yyyy-mm-dd strings directly.

Why the ancient Postgres 9.6? That version has reached end-of-life in 2021 (!) JSON support was still limited back then. Use a current version.
